# Can I pick up alien radio signals from my backyard?

Tags: seti

I would like to know please whether or not I can pick up alien radio signals from my backyard.

Comment: Sure, you can try. My recommendation is to buy this amateur radio telescope (https://www.primalucelab.com/radioastronomy/spider230-amateur-radio-telescope.html) between several people.

Also, you can directly help scientists find extraterrestial intelligence without the need of any telescope; here how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCdDS4j318UpKjNcpe_LeQxQ

Comment: In addition to the fine answer/comment above.   After some 40 years of listening (not sure when the big ear was built), No nation on the Earth has found a definitive alien signal.   If they are out there, they're hard to find.

Comment: @userLTK - You’re talking about undocumented aliens??? /s

Comment: Sometimes, picking up terrestrial radio signals is a problem.

Comment: Only if the aliens want to talk to you specifically.   They tell me I'm one of a very select group.

Answer (score 4):

This is like asking "can I spot polar bears from my back garden?"

There is nothing that would stop a determined polar bear from coming into my garden, so it is not impossible. But unless you live in Churchill, its probably not going to happen.

You can get a radio telescope, and it would be able to receive a sufficiently powerful signal. But detecting alien signals is hard: so far we haven't detected any. Even with big detectors.

Can you detect aliens: Yes.  Will you detect aliens: Probably not.